# Filtering and text to columns

Tags: excel, vba

So, I have a table, where new semicolon text is being pasted at the bottom of separated text which has already been separated based on their ';'.

So far, I use a filter to filter out the blanks in column C (as the new pasted text does not have anything in column C), and then on column B I perform text to columns. However, this over rights all the data in C,D,E,F even for rows which are hidden by the filter.

How do I perform text to column whilst not overwriting the pre-existing information, even though it has been filtered out and would not exist between the rows showing.

So far:

```
   With ActiveSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("A1:F1").AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=""
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.Select

    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.texttocolumns Destination:=ActiveCell, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=True, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 4), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
   ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-21

    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("A1:F1").AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:="<>"
End With
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: That's what "Text to Columns" is supposed to do.  If you don't want to overwrite data, then insert a column to the right.

Answer (score 0):

```
destination:=Range(?)
```

`?` is the new cell location you want to place the data generated after transformation. Then you don't erase any orginal data.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. Sorry. My intentions was to just expand the data where it is.